# Is it possible to disable "Continue where you left off" in Chrome without opening it?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have a computer with Windows 7 and I'm using Chrome. I selected the option "Continue where you left off" in Chrome. But when I open Chrome, there are too many windows and tabs which open and my computer gets stuck immediately (it's not responding and I have to restart it). Is it possible to disable this feature in Chrome without opening it? My computer works perfectly without Chrome, I can even open Firefox. If I don't find a solution I will have to start using Opera or Chrome Canary, but I prefer to solve the problem with Chrome and continue using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1 (Easy way): Delete the Current Session

I assume you have enabled the "Show hidden files" option in Windows.

1. Exit Chrome
2. Go to
   `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
3. Delete the file called `Current Session`.

You are done, but the option you selected is still there. So go to Settings and select "Open the new tab page".

### Option 2: Create a new browser user profile

I assume you have enabled the "Show hidden files" option in Windows.

1. Exit Google Chrome completely.
2. Enter the keyboard shortcut <kbd>[image] (Windows key)</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open Windows Explorer.
3. In the Windows Explorer window that appears, enter the following in the address bar:
   `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`
4. Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default".
5. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

[Extracted above steps from here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en)

6. Now, if you want to get back your bookmarks, simply copy the file called `bookmarks.bak` which is located at "Backup default" folder.
   (You may  have to disable the option "Hide extentions for known file types" to see `.bak`.) Paste it in the "Default" folder which you created just now. After pasting, remove the `.bak` extention.
7. Similarly if you want to get back history, copy the history file from the "Backup default" folder and paste it in the default folder.

Remember you can't have duplicates of bookmarks and history.

Now the option "Continue where you left off" should have been reset to the default choice, "Open the new tab page".

Comment: Thanks, option 1 worked! I didn't want to create a new profile, only to open Chrome without all my tabs. I'm keeping the option "Continue where you left off" for next time.

Comment: @Uri By the way, I don't know why your question has so many down votes.

Comment: Don't worry, it's OK. Thanks for the upvote!